# Extend javascript to use multiple canvas boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, touch

I have very little knowledge of javascript, sadly. I'm at the moment working on a script. I want to sign files online, possible with any kind of touchscreen. I've got a script online that delivers a little canvas box with signing-functionality. Sadly my javascript skills are too bad to use it the way I want.

```js
var isSign = false;
  var leftMButtonDown = false;
  
  jQuery(function(){
   //Initialize sign pad
   init_Sign_Canvas();
  });
  
  function fun_submit() {
   if(isSign) {
    var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
    jQuery('#page').find('p').remove();
    jQuery('#page').find('img').remove();
    jQuery('#page').append(jQuery('<p>Your Sign:</p>'));
    jQuery('#page').append($('<img/>').attr('src',imgData));
    
    closePopUp();
   } else {
    alert('Please sign');
   }
  }
  
  function closePopUp() {
   jQuery('#divPopUpSignContract').popup('close');
   jQuery('#divPopUpSignContract').popup('close');
  }
  
  function init_Sign_Canvas() {
   isSign = false;
   leftMButtonDown = false;
   
   //Set Canvas width
   var sizedWindowWidth = $(window).width();
   if(sizedWindowWidth > 700)
    sizedWindowWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
   else if(sizedWindowWidth > 400)
    sizedWindowWidth = sizedWindowWidth - 100;
   else
    sizedWindowWidth = sizedWindowWidth - 50;
    
    $("#canvas").width(200);
    $("#canvas").height(50);
    $("#canvas").css("border","1px solid #000");
   
    var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
   
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    if(canvasContext)
    {
     canvasContext.canvas.width  = 200;
     canvasContext.canvas.height = 50;

     canvasContext.fillStyle = "#fff";
     canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,sizedWindowWidth,200);
     
     canvasContext.moveTo(50,150);
     canvasContext.lineTo(sizedWindowWidth-50,150);
     canvasContext.stroke();
    
     canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
     canvasContext.font="20px Arial";
     canvasContext.fillText("x",40,155);
    }
    // Bind Mouse events
    $(canvas).on('mousedown', function (e) {
     if(e.which === 1) { 
      leftMButtonDown = true;
      canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
      var x = e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
      var y = e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
      canvasContext.moveTo(x, y);
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
   
    $(canvas).on('mouseup', function (e) {
     if(leftMButtonDown && e.which === 1) {
      leftMButtonDown = false;
      isSign = true;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
   
    // draw a line from the last point to this one
    $(canvas).on('mousemove', function (e) {
     if(leftMButtonDown == true) {
      canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
      var x = e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
      var y = e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
      canvasContext.lineTo(x,y);
      canvasContext.stroke();
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
    
    //bind touch events
    $(canvas).on('touchstart', function (e) {
    leftMButtonDown = true;
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
    var t = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var x = t.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
    var y = t.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
    canvasContext.moveTo(x, y);
    
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
    
    $(canvas).on('touchmove', function (e) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
    var t = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var x = t.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
    var y = t.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
    canvasContext.lineTo(x,y);
    canvasContext.stroke();
    
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
    
    $(canvas).on('touchend', function (e) {
    if(leftMButtonDown) {
     leftMButtonDown = false;
     isSign = true;
    }
    
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas">Canvas is not supported</canvas>
```

I need 3 canvas boxes, that can be signed parallel to each other. Is it possible to give me a hint or a tutorial or something that will make me understand what I need to change?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with: "I want to sign files online, possible with any kind of touchscreen."? Can you be more precise about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I really failed to explain what I meant, sorry about that. my problem is that I need 3 fields. Every field has to be signed by a different person and at the end there should be 3 png-files generated with the 3 signatures, so I can produce the PDF file. That's actually what I meant.. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you mean (maybe three independent sign-in boxes?).

Use 3 HTML5 `<canvas>` elements, and initialize them. Then use the `drawImage()` function to copy the first canvas image onto the canvas context of the other two.

```js
var isSign = false;
  var leftMButtonDown = false;
  
  jQuery(function(){
   //Initialize sign pad
   init_Sign_Canvas();
  });
  
  function fun_submit() {
   if(isSign) {
    var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
    jQuery('#page').find('p').remove();
    jQuery('#page').find('img').remove();
    jQuery('#page').append(jQuery('<p>Your Sign:</p>'));
    jQuery('#page').append($('<img/>').attr('src',imgData));
    
    closePopUp();
   } else {
    alert('Please sign');
   }
  }
  
  function closePopUp() {
   jQuery('#divPopUpSignContract').popup('close');
   jQuery('#divPopUpSignContract').popup('close');
  }
  
  function init_Sign_Canvas() {
   isSign = false;
   leftMButtonDown = false;
   
   //Set Canvas width
   var sizedWindowWidth = $(window).width();
   if(sizedWindowWidth > 700)
    sizedWindowWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
   else if(sizedWindowWidth > 400)
    sizedWindowWidth = sizedWindowWidth - 100;
   else
    sizedWindowWidth = sizedWindowWidth - 50;
    
    $("#canvas").width(200);
    $("#canvas").height(50);
    $("#canvas").css("border","1px solid #000");
    $("#canvas2").width(200);
    $("#canvas2").height(50);
    $("#canvas2").css("border","1px solid #000");
    $("#canvas3").width(200);
    $("#canvas3").height(50);
    $("#canvas3").css("border","1px solid #000");

    var canvas = $("#canvas").get(0);
      var canvas2 = $("#canvas2").get(0);
      var canvas3 = $("#canvas3").get(0);

    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
             canvas2ctx = canvas2.getContext('2d');
             canvas3ctx = canvas3.getContext('2d');
    if(canvasContext)
    {
     canvasContext.canvas.width  = 200;
     canvasContext.canvas.height = 50;
                 canvas2ctx.canvas.width  = 200;
     canvas2ctx.canvas.height = 50;
                 canvas3ctx.canvas.width  = 200;
     canvas3ctx.canvas.height = 50;
     canvasContext.fillStyle = "#fff";
     canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,sizedWindowWidth,200);
     
     canvasContext.moveTo(50,150);
     canvasContext.lineTo(sizedWindowWidth-50,150);
     canvasContext.stroke();
    
     canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
     canvasContext.font="20px Arial";
     canvasContext.fillText("x",40,155);
    }
    // Bind Mouse events
    $(canvas).on('mousedown', function (e) {
     if(e.which === 1) { 
      leftMButtonDown = true;
      canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
      var x = e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
      var y = e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
      canvasContext.moveTo(x, y);
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
   
    $(canvas).on('mouseup', function (e) {
     if(leftMButtonDown && e.which === 1) {
      leftMButtonDown = false;
      isSign = true;
                     canvas2ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
                     canvas3ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
   
    // draw a line from the last point to this one
    $(canvas).on('mousemove', function (e) {
     if(leftMButtonDown == true) {
      canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
      var x = e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
      var y = e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
      canvasContext.lineTo(x,y);
      canvasContext.stroke();
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
    
    //bind touch events
    $(canvas).on('touchstart', function (e) {
    leftMButtonDown = true;
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
    var t = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var x = t.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
    var y = t.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
    canvasContext.moveTo(x, y);
    
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
    
    $(canvas).on('touchmove', function (e) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000";
    var t = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var x = t.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left;
    var y = t.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top;
    canvasContext.lineTo(x,y);
    canvasContext.stroke();
    
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    });
    
    $(canvas).on('touchend', function (e) {
    if(leftMButtonDown) {
     leftMButtonDown = false;
     isSign = true;
    }
    
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas">Canvas is not supported</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2">Canvas is not supported</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3">Canvas is not supported</canvas>
```

Comment: I really failed to explain what I meant, sorry about that. my problem is that I need 3 fields. Every field has to be signed by a different person and at the end there should be 3 png-files generated with the 3 signatures, so I can produce the PDF file. That's actually what I meant.. Sorry..